# How to handle window open prompt(native) in webdriver.io

Tags: webdriver-io

I am using webdriver.io framework. At my application, I have a button that opens a Windows Open prompt (Native), and there I need to choose a folder/file and click Open.
Then returning to my application and continue.

Is there a way to move focus on to this window and control it (Select a path and click Open)?
If not- Is there any other solution someone can offer?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is *probably not*, you can't control native dialogs from webdriver.
If it's a file input type for which you want to set a file, you might possibly use webdriver to evaluate a piece of javascript to set the `HTMLInputElement.files` value of the input element.

This works in modern browsers as mentioned in the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)